# Issue in my result eqution using javascript

Tags: javascript-objects

I have an issue with result - this is my code into result.js file

```
function FtotalCat(){
var a=document.getElementById("Ftotal").value;

  if (a <= '5') {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Low-risk";
  } else if (a >= '5' && a <= '7.4') {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Borderline-risk";
  } else if (a >= '7.5' && a <= '19.9') {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Intermediate-risk";
  } else if (a >= '20') {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="High-risk";
  }

 }
```

but result always see with any number "Low-Risk" - When apply this code with online code editor everything running good - but in my application not I don't know why??

I tried to edit equations to put number with "" or '' but same issue

I tried to remove this "" and '' but code not working

Answer (score 0):

Check data type of a using
`console.log(typeof a)` if a is number then use 5 instead of '5'. and also use double equal to to match data type also.